# How to see assembly code in basic block on IDA pro

Tags: ida, reversing

I reversing my test program on IDA.
I want to see Control Flaw Graph that basic block has instructions. But my IDA only show me the function name. . .

This is my IDA pro screen
[image]

And This is what I want to see
[image]

Please help me . . .